# How to make the screen adaptive to small screens in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

when developing android apps there exist a missing layout when I run it in small screen size.

is there something that can make user scroll to show the hidden part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie this right fill scrollview whit your buttons but make sure that buttons put in the linearlayout an this linear put into scrollview

Comment: i really don't know how this is some of my code 
https://ideone.com/TPSudf

Comment: <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">  PUT MANY BUTTONS HERE THATS IT</LinearLayout> </ScrollView>

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) in your layout files, which allows it to be larger than the physical display. Therefore, in small screens where the layout cannot be displayed completely, the view can be scrolled by the user.

(Note make sure do NOT use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling)